# Get rows and columns in excel file that are not null

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Hi can you help me get Rows and Columns in excel that are not empty. I am doing a project that gets data in excel and display it in datagridview but it also get the rows and columns that are null or empty.

Answer (score 1):

use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` function before adding values into `DataGridView`.

Try This:

```
string str="/*assign cell value from excel*/";
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{

//now Add the cell value to DataGridView as cell is not empty

}
```

**Note :** if you can edit question with your code, it would be easy to solve the issue.